# Angular callback functions default value

Tags: typescript

I have been using callback functions a lot in Angular, but that was before I upgraded my angular version from v9 to v12.

Normally, when I build an Angular application, I create different controllers to retrieve data from the http service. So one of the methods of such a controller is like this:

```ts
/**
   * Deletes a building with the specified identifier
   * @param id identification number of the building
   * @param callback return function with an error object
   */
  deleteBuilding(id: string, callback: Function = null) {
    this._http.requestCall<any>(ApiMethod.DELETE, false, AppEndPoints.LIST_BUILDINGS, id).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.count == 1) {
        if (callback) callback(false);
      } else {
        this.apm.messageErrorChange("Building has not been deleted");
        if (callback) callback(true);
      }
    }, (err) => {
      this.apm.messageErrorChange("There was an error while deleting the building");
      if (callback) callback(true);
    });
  }
```

Which seems okay to me, except now I get an error saying: `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Function'.`

If you can't assign null or undefined to a function, then what should the default value be in this case, and what is the reason behind this?

I hope someone can help me with this!

Thanks in advance,

Billy Cottrell

Comment: You can use `callback: Function | null = null` then

Comment: Does this also work for `var user : User = null`?

Comment: `User` is probably not `null` so you can't/shouldn't do that. `var user?: User` or `var user: User | null` should be better